# web service returns null insead of List<MyCustomObj> in Java

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans

I use `Netbeans 7.4` for my `Java` development. I try to use web service client/server application.
I am hiving a strange problem, let me describe it in details. 
At server side, suppose i have `DeviceInfo` and `LocationInfo` classes like the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="DeviceInfo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "DeviceInfo")
public class DeviceInfo {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

`LocationInfo` class has a member of `DeviceInfo` type:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="LocationInfo")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "LocationInfo")
public class LocationInfo {

    @XmlElement(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "DeviceInfo", type=DeviceInfo.class)
    private DeviceInfo deviceInfo;

public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

public DeviceInfo getDeviceInfo() {
    return deviceInfo;
}

public void setDeviceInfo(DeviceInfo deviceInfo) {
    this.deviceInfo = deviceInfo;
}
}
```

And my web service class is like:

```
@WebService
public class DbAccess {

    public List<LocationInfo> getListLocation()
    {
        List<LocationInfo> listLocation = new ArrayList<>();

        LocationInfo location1 = new LocationInfo();
        location1.setName("Location 1");
        DeviceInfo device1_1 = new DeviceInfo();
        device1_1.setName("Device1_1");
        location1.setDeviceInfo(device1_1);
        listLocation.add(location1);

        LocationInfo location2 = new LocationInfo();
        location2.setName("Location 2");
        DeviceInfo device2_1 = new DeviceInfo();
        device2_1.setName("Device2_1");
        location2.setDeviceInfo(device2_1);
        listLocation.add(location2);

        return listLocation;
    }
}
```

The web service simply returns list of LocationInfo. 
At web client side, I simply added a `web service client` from `Netbeans`(New/Web Service Client). I just gave the web service WSDL address to IDE and it imported the web service types. So i can consume the web service at client side. The problem is that my web client gets `null` deviceInfo from `getDeviceInfo`() function of `LocationInfo`.
The code that i use in web client:

```
DbAccessService srv = new DbAccessService();
    DbAccess db = srv.getDbAccessPort();
    List<LocationInfo> list = db.getListLocation();
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {
        String str = "-" + list.get(i).getName();
        if(list.get(i).getDeviceInfo() == null)
            str += "\r\n---NULL";
        else
            str += "\r\n---" + list.get(i).getDeviceInfo().getName();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

This produces the following output:

```
-Location 1
---NULL
-Location 2
---NULL
```

Why do i get null insead of actual DeviceInfo?

Comment: Maybe try removing @XmlRootElement(name="DeviceInfo")

Comment: @j.con it solved the problem! i removed `@XmlRootElement` annotation and now i can get the value insead of null. Thank you. But what is the logic, why did i have to remove that?

Comment: good deal. The web service sends the data as Xml, if you are familiar with Xml, there is always *one* root element. For example `<root> <attribute1></attribute1> <attribute2></attribute2> </root>`

Comment: @j.con so the service doesn't send the `<root>` tag for `DeviceInfo` anymore? Did this do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit* let me post as an answer for better formatting

No `<root>` was never used in your case, I just put that for an example. In your instance, since `LocationInfo` holds a `DevinceInfo` you want `LocationInfo` to be the *root* element. Defining `DeviceInfo` as a root element also confused the marshaller. Your Xml will look like

```
<LocationInfo>
   <name>
      Location 1
   </name>
   <DeviceInfo>
      <name>
         Device_1
      </name>
   </DeviceInfo>
</LocationInfo>
```

see how `LocationInfo` is the root element, defined by `@XmlRootElement`